# How to display my values in props array horizontally

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my React project I have to take an array from parent component and print it in child component(PrintHorizontal) horizontally.

I am using map function which renders my values vertically so I wrote join to combine array values but I am getting different value. Print is my child component

```
props.values=[
   {
    id:1,
    x:1
   },
   {
    id:1,
    x:1
   }
 ]

PrintHorizontal Component:
const PrintHorizontal = props => {  
let list=props.values.map(value => {      
    return <Print key={value.id} data={value.x} />
 });
return (
    <div>
        {list.join(' , ')}
    </div>
)
}

Print Component:
const Print = props => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Avatar>{props.data}</Avatar>  //Avatar is a component imported from materialUI
        </div>
    )
}
```

I expect run values would be printed horizontally instead I am getting
[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: Can you post your `props.value` array?

Comment: The edit completely changes the question. Please be respectful of people's time and ensure that your question is accurate and complete before asking it. More in the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: We cannot answer this for you based on the information in the above. We'd need to know what the `Print` component *renders*. That's what determines how the browser ends up rendering it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Print component is wrapped inside div also it seems Avtar component add it's own div so you can simply return Avtar from print, and to parent div use display: flex to align them horizontally.

```
const PrintHorizontal = props => {
return (
    <div className="horizontal">
        { props.values.map(value => {
            <Print key={value.id} data={value.x} />
        })}
    </div>
)
}

const Print = props => {
    return (
            <Avatar>{props.data}</Avatar>  //Avatar is a component imported from materialUI
    )
}
```

In your css file

```
.horizontal {
    display: flex;
    align-item: center;
}
```

Comment: No luck. I have changed div tags to span in both the components.

Comment: seems Avtar is also adding its own div. updated my answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script>
        main = () => {
            const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
            const list = arr.map(item => {
                const node = document.createElement('span');
                node.innerHTML = item * 2; 
                node.style.margin = '20px';
                return node;
            });

            list.forEach(element => {
                document.getElementById("target").appendChild(element)
            })
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="main()">
    <div id="target"></div>
</body>

</html>
```